# Threads only run once in FileSystemWatcher changed

Tags: c#, .net

Each time a file is changed some forms need to be created but the FileSystemWatcher_Changed method only works once and I don't know why.
First time a txt is changed it work correctly but if i make a second change the FileSystemWatcher_Changed method is not called again.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RunFileSystemWatcher();
    }
    [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public void RunFileSystemWatcher()
    {
        FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher();
        fsw.Path = "C:/";
        fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess;
        fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;


        //fsw.Created += FileSystemWatcher_Created;
        fsw.Changed += FileSystemWatcher_Changed;
        fsw.Filter = "*.txt";
        fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    }

    private void FileSystemWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {           
       // ThreadStart delegado = new ThreadStart(showForms);           
        Thread hilo = new Thread(()=> showForms(e));            
        hilo.Start();            
    }

    private void showForms(FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {                  //leer fichero                   
                foreach (DataRow dr in r.asientosByTxt(e.FullPath).Rows)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(dr[1].ToString());
                    Thread hilo2 = new Thread(() => Formsss(new Form2());
                    hilo2.Start();
                }                
    } 
    private void Formsss(Form2 jugador)
    {
        Application.Run(jugador);

    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place. You can't modify the UI from a background thread, in any operating system. You don't *need* to do so anyway.

Comment: I delete that part beacause it has nothing to do with the problem

Comment: On the contrary, that's probably what causes the application to crash. Even if you don't observe an exception, those threads will never be able to display anything

Comment: If you want to dispaly a popup box for every change use a *modeless* window in the event and update its contents. Use `Show` instead of `ShowDialog`.

Comment: I comment that and try to use showdialog but still dont work

Comment: Using what code? As long as you insist on using a thread, you won't see anything on the UI